# Capabilities of Sudoers and Sudoreplay Logging and Playback

Tags: rhel, sudo, logs

Is the `sudoers` file in RHEL limited to configuring logging to only what is typed on the keyboard, output on the screen, or errors thrown, or can it go beyond this?

For example, if I want to record a `vim` session where the user edits a file, can I get a replay of this editing in real time?

Are there any additional configurations of `sudoers` or another file that would make this a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Sudo doesn’t provide those capabilities.  There are some hacks with ‘script’ that can record a shell session, but I’m not sure what to expect from running vim in the session.